# Facebook Like Button On My Website To Like A Facebook Page, Not My Website

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-like, xfbml

I have a Facebook like button on my website, however as it works currently it only lets users like the page that they are currently on. Is it possible to make the button like our Facebook page instead of our website?

Comment: Sounds like a great idea but be aware you will be pushing users back to facebook rather than back to *your* website

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [badge creator](https://www.facebook.com/badges/page.php) to create a badge for your page that a user can interact with for "like" purposes.

Comment: Hmm, that's not exactly what I had in mind. You know how you can like a website, is there nothing that lets you like a Facebook page in the same manner without using Facebook badges?

Comment: Ah, then [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) should work for you. Just use the URL for your page e.g. http://facebook.com/dwaynespage.

Comment: Haha, I feel like an idiot. Why didn't I just think to put the url to the page in the like generator. Thanks Matt.

Comment: No problem. There is also the "like box" generator [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) if that suits you better.

Answer (score 12):

Go to the developers [page which provides Social Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). There, just add at the "URL to Like" of the button, the address of your facebook page. E.g. http://www.facebook.com/mypage

[image]

This way, once the users push the like button, your facebook page will get automatically a like and they will also follow the updates of the facebook page

Answer (score 2):

you could try this page this might work better for you, they can like the facebook page direct on your site http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: This feature is deprecated since 2017.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't put your right page url in facebook like box generator. Go to you facebook page and copy the link from there. Now use this to generate facebook like box. You can also get help from this http://www.codematrics.com/my-website-and-facebook-page-have-different-likes/